# unexpected unqualified id error

Tags: c++

```
expected unqualified-id before string constant in member function set_linux().
```

I am getting this error during compilation of my code. I have added class and main function over here.

```
expected before '}' before end of line
```

Code:

```
#include "Timer.h"

Timer::Timer() {
    now = 0;
    is_init = 0;

    #if defined (_linux)
        set_linux();
    #elif defined (_APPLE)
        set_apple();
    #elif defined (_WIN32)
        set_win32();
    #endif // defined
}
void Timer::set_apple() {
    #define HAVE_MACH_TIMER
    //#include <mach/mach_time.h>
}
void Timer::set_linux() {
    #define HAVE_POSIX_TIMER
    #include <time.h>
    #ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC
        #define CLOCKID CLOCK_MONOTONIC
    #else
        #define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME
    #endif // CLOCK_MONOTONIC
}
void Timer::set_win32() {
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <windows.h>
}
void Timer::apple() {
    static mach_timebase_info_data_t info;
    if (0 == is_init) {
        mach_timebase_info(&info);
        is_init = 1;
    }
    now = mach_absolute_time();
    now *= info.numer;
    now /= info.denom;
}
void Timer::linux() {
    static struct timespec linux_rate;
    if (0 == is_init) {
        clock_getres(CLOCKID, &linux_rate);
        is_init = 1;
    }
    struct timespec spec;
    clock_gettime(CLOCKID, &spec);
    now = spec.tv_sec * 1.0e9 + spec.tv_nsec;
}
void Timer::win32() {
    static LARGE_INTEGER win_frequency;
    if (0 == is_init) {
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&win_frequency);
        is_init = 1;
    }
    LARGE_INTEGER now;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&now);
    this->now = (uint64_t) ((1e9 * now.QuadPart) / win_frequency.QuadPart);
}
static uint64_t Timer::ns() {
    #if defined (_APPLE_)
        apple();
        return now;
    #elif defined (_linux)
        linux();
        return now;
    #elif defined(_WIN32)
        win32();
        return now;
    #endif // defined
}

using namespace std;

int main() {

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are you `#include <time.h>` inside `set_linux()`?

Comment: Formatted error messages.  Not sure now to fix wording to lead into second error.

Answer (score 1):

You should not #include stuff within a function or namespace scope because it makes it harder to see (and you are defining it content under the local scope rather than the global scope where they reside in this case).  Moreover, what you are doing will cause compilation issues on each platform.  What you probably want is to conditionally #include and #define your values based on the platform at the top.

```
#include "Timer.h"

#if defined (_linux)
# define HAVE_POSIX_TIMER
# include <time.h>
# ifdef CLOCK_MONOTONIC
#  define CLOCKID CLOCK_MONOTONIC
# else
#  define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME
# endif // CLOCK_MONOTONIC
#elif defined (_APPLE)
# define HAVE_MACH_TIMER
//# include <mach/mach_time.h>
#elif defined (_WIN32)
# define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
# include <windows.h>
#endif

Timer::Timer() {
    now = 0;
    is_init = 0;
    // This portion may no longer be applicable.
#if defined (_linux)
    set_linux();
#elif defined (_APPLE)
    set_apple();
#elif defined (_WIN32)
    set_win32();
#endif // defined
}
void Timer::set_apple() {
}
void Timer::set_linux() {
}
void Timer::set_win32() {
}
void Timer::apple() {
    static mach_timebase_info_data_t info;
    if (0 == is_init) {
        mach_timebase_info(&info);
        is_init = 1;
    }
    now = mach_absolute_time();
    now *= info.numer;
    now /= info.denom;
}
void Timer::linux() {
    static struct timespec linux_rate;
    if (0 == is_init) {
        clock_getres(CLOCKID, &linux_rate);
        is_init = 1;
    }
    struct timespec spec;
    clock_gettime(CLOCKID, &spec);
    now = spec.tv_sec * 1.0e9 + spec.tv_nsec;
}
void Timer::win32() {
    static LARGE_INTEGER win_frequency;
    if (0 == is_init) {
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&win_frequency);
        is_init = 1;
    }
    LARGE_INTEGER now;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&now);
    this->now = (uint64_t) ((1e9 * now.QuadPart) / win_frequency.QuadPart);
}
static uint64_t Timer::ns() {
#if defined (_APPLE_)
        apple();
        return now;
#elif defined (_linux)
        linux();
        return now;
#elif defined(_WIN32)
        win32();
        return now;
#endif // defined
}

using namespace std;

int main() {

 return 0;
}
```